# Get child elements from a specific cell in an HTMLTableRowElement and hide/remove them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grid, telerik-mvc

I am working with some custom ajax functionality using Telerik's MVC Grid and I am trying to hide/remove child elements of a cell based on specific criteria, I found a similar question here: [Telerik MVC Grid making a Column Red Color based on Other Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094352/telerik-mvc-grid-making-a-column-red-color-based-on-other-column-value) but couldn't get it working right.

Basically when the row is databound in the grid this event fires:

```
 function onRowDataBound(e) {
        if (e.dataItem.Status == "Submitted") {
            $.each(e.row.cells, function (index, column) {
                alert(column.innerHTML);
                //var $header = $(column).closest('table').find('th').eq($(column).index());
                //if(header text == "Actions)
                //{
                     //Get the <a> child elements in the 'Actions' column whose class contains t-grid-Edit, 
                     //t-grid-edit, t-grid-Delete, or t-grid-delete and set their display to none, add a css class, and remove the element entirely
                //}
            }

        }
    }
```

So far it's working in that I can get and iterate through each column in the row, but I am not sure what to do at this point, I found this [How can I get the corresponding table header (th) from a table cell (td)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523770/how-can-i-get-the-corresponding-table-header-th-from-a-table-cell-td) to check to make sure the column name name is Actions, but I couldn't get it working. I am not sure how to convert the javascript HTMLTableCellElement object into a jQuery object so I can use syntax I am more familiar with.

Here is what I need to do after that:

1. Get the  child elements in the 'Actions' (has to go by column header name instead of cell index because the number of columns can change) column whose class
   contains t-grid-Edit, t-grid-edit, t-grid-Delete, or t-grid-delete
2. Take those  elements and (each of these actions would be used on different pages using similar setups):

   - a. Set the element's display style to none
   - b. Add a class to the element of name "Hidden"
   - c. Remove the  element from the code entirely

How can I put the above functionality into my `onRowDataBound` function?

Thank you SO =).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with a lot of playing:

```
function onRowDataBound(e) {
        if(e.dataItem.Status == "Submitted"){
            var $row = $(e.row);
            $.each($row.children("td"), function (index, column) {
                var $column = $(column);
                var $headerText = $column.closest('table').find('th').eq($column.index()).children(".t-link").text();
                if ($headerText == "Actions") {
                    $.each($column.children("a.t-grid-delete, a.t-grid-Edit"), function (subIndex, link) {
                        $(link).remove();

                    });
                }

            }); 
        }
    }
```