# How to set font-weight of a column text to bold based on another column value in Telerik Grid

Tags: telerik, formatting, conditional-statements, client-templates

I have a Telerik grid in which based on whether my IsTrue value is true or false, I need to set the font-weight of Name text in only that particular row to bold. I tried the following but I seem to be missing something.

```
columns.Bound(d => d.IsTrue).Width(0).HtmlAttributes(new { id="hdnIsTrue", style = "visibility:hidden;" });
columns.Bound(d => d.Name).ClientTemplate("#<#= hdnIsTrue ? font-weight : bold : font-weight : normal #>#" + "# } #")
                            .Title("Name").Width(200);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my code to the following with help from the post:
[Telerik MVC Grid making a Column Red Color based on Other Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094352/telerik-mvc-grid-making-a-column-red-color-based-on-other-column-value/7113908#7113908)

```
.Columns(columns =>
         {columns.Bound(d => d.IsTrue).Width(0);
          columns.Bound(d => d.Name).Title("Name).Width(200).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:normal;" });

}).CellAction(cell => {
                        if (cell.Column.Title == "Name"){
                              var item = cell.DataItem;
                              if(item.IsTrue) {
                                  cell.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "font-weight : bold;";
                              }}}).Render();
```